# How to italicize text on watchOS 3 complication?

Tags: watchos, clockkit

If you look at the calendar complication on watchOS 3, the second row of text below the date is italicized. I've searched the documentation high and low but can't find anything.

I'm using all three providers in `CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody` but all three rows of text are formatted with non-italicized text.

Is there a trick to making the third provider italicized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like italics is a form of data detectors - in this case addresses, so I don't think there's a public API for this.